# Why doesn't swift infer the appropriate overload function with a generic return argument without a type constraint?

Tags: swift, generics, overloading, type-inference

**Note**

Swift is changing rapidly, this question was asked regarding:

> **Xcode 7, Swift 2.0**

**Explanation**

I'm looking to implement a generic return argument.  Quite often, I find it necessary to implement an optional version overload so I can access the underlying type and handle it appropriately.  Here's some manufactured functions.  The assignment of String is just there as a placeholder for replication:

```
func ambiguous<T>() -> T {
    let thing = "asdf"
    return thing as! T
}

func ambiguous<T>() -> T? {
    return nil
}
```

Now, if we look at the implementation:

```
// Fine
let a: String = ambiguous()

// Ambiguous
let b: String? = ambiguous()
```

This might seem obvious because you could assign type `T` to a variable of type `T?`.  So it makes sense that it would have trouble inferring. The problem is, that with a type constraint, it suddenly works.  (This can be anything, I'm using `Equatable` for easy replication.

```
func nonAmbiguous<T : Equatable>() -> T {
    let thing: AnyObject = "asdf"
    return thing as! T
}

func nonAmbiguous<T : Equatable>() -> T? {
    return nil
}
```

And now, it functions as expected:

```
// Fine
let c: String = nonAmbiguous()

// Fine
let d: String? = nonAmbiguous()
```

Note, this also works with other type:

```
func nonAmbiguous<T>() -> [T] {
    let thing: AnyObject = ["asdf"]
    return thing as! [T]
}

func nonAmbiguous<T>() -> [T]? {
    return nil
}

// Fine
let e: [String] = nonAmbiguous()

// Fine
let d: [String]? = nonAmbiguous()
```

**Question:**

Is there a way to have a return generic argument infer the appropriate overload through optionality?

**if no**

Is this a language feature, or a bug somewhere.  If it's a language feature, please explain the underlying issue preventing the possibility of this behavior.

Comment: Your second example is not ambiguous because `String` is `Equatable` but `String?` is not.

Comment: Ahh, I see what you're saying @MartinR.  Because when it is just `T`, an argument of type `T?` conforms to both, but when I add the type constraint, `Optional<T>` no longer conforms, so it's no longer ambiguous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first example is ambiguous because `T` can be inferred as both `String`
and `String?`.

The second example is not ambiguous because `String` is `Equatable` but `String?` is not, so `T : Equatable` cannot be inferred as `String?`.

The third case is not ambiguous because `[T]` is not
inferred as `[String]?`.

*Remark:* Generally, `Optional<Wrapped>` does not conform to `Equatable`
even if `Wrapped` does, in the same way as `Array<Element>`
does not conform to `Equatable` even if `Element` does.
This is a restriction of the current type system in Swift which
might be improved in a future version, compare

- [[swift-dev] RFC: Adding Optional variants of == for collections to   the std lib](https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-dev/Week-of-Mon-20151130/000061.html).

from the Swift development mailing list.